# How can I send data from nodejs to js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I want to send a string or a object from nodejs to a string or a object in js.

I alredy have this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();

app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'static')));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    const dir = req.query.dir;
    fs.readdir('./'+ dir,(err, data)=>{
        console.log(data);
    });
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'static','index.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

In a example this outputs to the console a object: ['index.html','css','js'].
My objective is to send that object to javascript to treat the object and them use it on html.

Comment: *"How can I send data from nodejs to js?"* Well in `javascript` you ca create an event listener for an event posted via `nodejs` and you can pass arguments/params within it.... Can you give a better example of what you have tried and your expected output please?

Comment: i need that data on the conole.log to go to a variable in the script of index.html. I try the event but unsuccessfully

Comment: Are you trying to get data/parmas from the URL and wanting to send that back to `javascript`? I am just guessing from the source code you have provided because I find your question unclear and missing relevant information.

Comment: in the url i pass a directory, then in the code i use fs.readdir() to create a object in the variable data with the files inside that directory. my english is bad, i can't explain me good sorry.

Comment: So from the **URL** you take the path to target a specific directory and wish to return all files from that directory as an object? Is that what you are trying to do? Sorry, I am trying to understand your expectations from the source code you have provided.

Comment: Yes right that, in my source i just put the way i get that object. i have no idea how can i solve my problem.